# SSL Certificate on Container Optimized OS (Docker)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, port, certbot

Question: How do you make web traffic run through certbot server and THEN to your app when port 80/443 can only be assigned to one server within Container Opimized OS?

Context:
Regular certbot install doesn't work for Google Cloud's "Container Optimzed OS" (which prevents write access, so no file can be executed). So I used a docker container of cerbot from letsencrypt, but it requires port 80/443 to be open, which my current web app is using.

Previously I would run certbot and then stop the server on my old instance and the certification would remain for 90 days. However, running the certbot docker container only gives SSL while it runs on port 80/443, but once stopped, SSL certificate is no longer valid.

Docker for letsencrypt: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt

Docker web app I want to host on port 80/443: https://hub.docker.com/r/lbjay/canvas-docker

Google Container Optimized Instance Info: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits

Comment: You can issue your cert with other tools like [Get HTTPS for free!](https://gethttpsforfree.com/). Also, what is your HTTP server? You see, if you are using NGINX you can modify your SERVER directive to forward your traffic to the letsencrypt container when the "http://<YOUR_DOMAIN>/.well-known/acme-challenge/" is reached. My second question for you is, why the certificate is no longer valid? That looks like a terrible and odd behavior.

Comment: Are you using Cloud DNS in GCP?  There's a clean solution if you're willing to expose some Cloud DNS roles with a service account in the official [certbot/dns-google](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/dns-google/) image.  ([documentation for the plugin](https://certbot-dns-google.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas thank you so much for answering. The HTTP server is apache, it comes with the Canvas app docker's image and its supposed to check for a folder in /etc/apache2 for the credentials apparently, but that folder doesn't exist. But I have not tried NGINX yet. I can try installing it within the Canvas app docker image perhaps. 

The original certification expired after 90 days. The renewal process cannot run without port 80/443 being exposed.

Comment: @rpatel Yes! I am using cloud DNS. I installed certbot docker and ran the /dns-google, but it fails with a google related error. I can try to run it again and copy and paste the error here since that would be more explicit.

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas I tried the "Get HTTPS for free" and it almost worked except for the very final step as this docker container is using Redis instead of Apache or Nginx already to serve the web app (did not know this before). 

I added certification paths to redis.conf file => http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf 
as described in documentation but does not work. 

I think your method would work for apache/nginx servers, so I will attempt to use a different docker image with apache or nginx.

Comment: @rpatel Here is the error from the docker certbot/dns-google: 

Encountered error finding managed zone: `<HttpError 401 when requesting https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/p4h-teach/managedZones?dnsName=admin.p4hteach.org.&alt=json returned "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">`

I tried following the link, but its a 404 error. Not sure how to use OAuth 2 access token for my dns?

Comment: My best guess is that your container is trying to interact with Cloud DNS without the necessary credentials.  I posted an answer with some info on how to run the container with service account credentials

Comment: @rpatel you were correct as the service key not being passed into my docker run was the issue as you showed in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for using DNS validation for Certbot via Cloud DNS in the [`certbot/dns-google`](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/dns-google/) container image. It will use service account credentials to run the [certbot-dns-google](https://certbot-dns-google.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) plugin in an executable container; this will configure the LetsEncrypt certs in a bind-mounted location on the host.

You'll first need to add a file to your instance with [service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) for the [*DNS Administrator* role](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/access-control#roles) - see the notes below for more context. In the example command below, the credentials file is *dns-svc-account.json* (placed in the working directory from which the command is called).

```sh
docker run --rm \
    -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:rw \
    -v ${PWD}/dns-svc-acct.json:/var/dns-svc-acct.json \
    certbot/dns-google certonly \
        --dns-google \
        --dns-google-credentials /var/dns-svc-acct.json \
        --dns-google-propagation-seconds 90 \
        --agree-tos -m team@site.com --non-interactive \
        -d site.com
```

Some notes on the flags:

- `-v` *`config-dir-mount`*

  > This mounts the configuration directory so that the files Certbot creates in the container propagate in the host's filesystem as well.
- `-v` *`credentials-file-mount`*

  > This mounts the service account credentials from the host on the container.
- `--dns-google-credentials` *`path-to-credentials`*

  > The container will use the mounted service account credentials for administering changes in Cloud DNS for validation with the ACME server (involves creating and removing a DNS TXT record).
- `--dns-google-propagation-seconds` *`n`* | *optional, default: 60*
- `--agree-tos`, `-m` *`email`*, `--non-interactive` | *optional*

  > These can be helpful for running the container non-interactively; they're particularly useful when user interaction might not be possible (e.g. continuous delivery).
- [*Certbot command-line reference*](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-command-line-options)

Comment: Just confirmed this by testing it out on a new Container Optimized OS instance. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! So this won't prevent an app from usuing port 80 on the host then? I will go ahead and try to implement this.

Comment: Yeah, this method won't require any http ingress to your instance.  It'll handle the validation through DNS, so your app/server can continue serving as normal.

Comment: Hey @rpatel,
I tried your solution and was closed but the JSON file gets mounted as a directory, using your command. 
I just added `${PWD}` in `    -v ${PWD}/dns-svc-acct.json:/var/dns-svc-acct.json \` and it worked perfectly.

Do you think your answer should be updated accordingly?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - bind mounts take absolute paths (if not using docker compose).  I added an edit to reflect that.  Thanks!